# Google Play is not accepting apk

Tags: jquery, cordova, google-play, android-manifest, dreamweaver

I am using jQuery mobile & Phonegap with Dreamweaver CS5.5. I created a few apps on my PC. Now I try to post them on Google Play but I get the same error. I am not a core developer, I just only know HTML, jQuery & PHP. I searched everywhere but can't find an answer.

I got this error when I uploaded the apk.

[image]

Check my HTML code
http://pastebin.com/X29B5ARv

How do I create AndroidManifest.xml for Dreamweaver applications?

Comment: did you write the app in java?

Comment: Sounds like you're writing a web app that needs to be hosted, not an Android app.

Comment: @tymeJV it really could go either way.  If you are unfamiliar with phonegap take a look: http://phonegap.com/ It's an attempt to bridge the divide from programmatic to declarative development in order to allow users only versed in scripting languages to build relatively robust applications.  It's a really cool concept for web designers and what not...I'm not sure how great it is but I do know you can package Phonegap apps for almost every mobile OS

Answer (score 0):

Here are the initial steps for publishing to Google Play:

- Register for a Google Play publisher account
- If you will sell apps, set up a Google Checkout Merchant Account
- Explore the Google Play Developer Console and learn about the tools for publishing

Check out more here: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/register.html

I haven't actually published anything for Android/Google Play but I'm like 99% certain Google Play apps need to be developed for Android, which means you need to use Java or some wrapper like [MonoDroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid).

It sounds like your PhoneGap project isn't compiled correctly if you are receiving an error for AndroidManifest.xml as it is a mandatory file for apps on Android (educated speculation).  I haven't used it before but make sure you compile it, or whatever you do in PhoneGap when you are building an RC/Release version, for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the Html file of yours, you have just made the simple Html page without using the Corodova/PhoneGap deviceReady function.
please take a look at [Phonegap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/index.html) to compile the App for Android.